# Azure Cognitive Services - Speech to text: Microphone not detected

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

**Question**: Why the following code is not detecting Microphone on my Windows 10? Without code, Microphone is working fine and I can use it by clicking `Window key + H`. I can speak on it and it can write that my spoken speech into any focused text editor. So, in the following code, I am wondering what I may be missing and how can we fix it?

**Details:** On my `WPF .NET 5` app, I am following `Recognize from microphone` section of [Get started with speech-to-text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speech-to-text?tabs=windowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-csharp) tutorial from Microsoft. They are using a Console App, I am using WPF app. As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/overview#create-the-azure-resource), I created an Azure Speech service resource and entered the subscription-key and the region in the code below, as well.

When I run the app, as shown in the image below, one can verify that there is no Microphone to be found on the screen. Generally when it opens it shows up on top of the screen. But in some rare cases you see its icon on the bottom right corner of the window - and by clicking on it, you can bring it up on top and start speaking on it.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("IEnteredMyAzureCognitiveServiceSubscriptionKeyHere", "eastus");
        _ = FromMic(speechConfig);
    }

    async static Task FromMic(SpeechConfig speechConfig)
    {
        using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        using var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        MessageBox.Show("Speak into your microphone.");
        var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}");
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

After I moved the two code lines from Constructor to a Button_Click(...) event as follows, then after clicking the button, I do get to see the Microphone icon on the lower right corner of the windows task bar. But when I click on that icon, instead of opening the Microphone, it opens the following settings window. But that did not help since I need the Microphone to open for a user to start speaking to it:

```
private async void btnRecogSpeech_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("My subscription key here", "eastus");
    await FromMic(speechConfig);
}
```

[image]

Comment: FromMic should be awaited, e.g. in an async Loaded event handler:  `Loaded += async (s, e) => await FromMic(speechConfig);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll down in the settings app and give your app permission to open the microphone.

Once you've done that, your app will be able to access the microphone and you'll be able to make progress.

Comment: The bottom half portion of the second Screenshot of my post above shows the list of the apps that have access to the Microphone. And those apps listed are: `Microsoft Edge, Speech Recognition, Speech Runtime Executable, Speech UX Configuration, MyWPFApp4Speech2TextTEST.` None of these apps have any other option (a button, a right click menu etc.) that you can use to configure further. So, I assume all these apps including mine (the last one in the list) have permission to the Microphone. One can get to that settings by clicking on `Privacy` link on the Windows Settings Home page.

Comment: And the Option button under the `Allow desktop apps to access you microphone` section of the above settings window is turned `on`. And the apps listed in my above comment are listed under this section. I also tried running `VS2019` as Administrator but still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

In the given code example, you are not doing await for the task, that is probably the reason why your program just exits and you do not see transcriptions output from the program. Please try following:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SpeechConfig speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("IEnteredMyAzureCognitiveServiceSubscriptionKeyHere", "eastus");
        await FromMic(speechConfig);
    }
```

Also please check Azure Speech SDK quickstarts here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/csharp

Comment: You can not `await` in a constructor, because it can not be declerad `async`. An async Loaded event handler would work.

Comment: @Clemens After reading your comment, I have just added an **UPDATE** section to the post - in case you or someone has any suggestion.